# Unnecessary warning coming from glasfish server (3.1.2)

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, ear

Why below warning is coming in glasfish server?

```
WARNING: LDR5206: ASURLClassLoader EarLibClassLoader : 
doneCalled = true
doneSnapshot = ASURLClassLoader.done() called ON EarLibClassLoader : 
urlSet = []
doneCalled = false 
 Parent -> org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@2e47ba
 AT Wed Apr 27 11:03:54 IST 2016 
 BY :java.lang.Throwable: printStackTraceToString
    at com.sun.enterprise.util.Print.printStackTraceToString(Print.java:639)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.done(ASURLClassLoader.java:211)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.preDestroy(ASURLClassLoader.java:179)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarClassLoader.preDestroy(EarClassLoader.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.clean(ApplicationInfo.java:400)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.undeploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.UndeployCommand.execute(UndeployCommand.java:330)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.handleRedeploy(DeployCommand.java:607)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:274)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Parent -> org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@2e47ba
 was requested to find resource META-INF/services/org.apache.axis.EngineConfigurationFactory after done was invoked from the following stack trace
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findResource(ASURLClassLoader.java:507)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1147)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1142)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1142)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.jdk.JDK12Hooks.getResources(JDK12Hooks.java:149)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.DiscoverResources$1.getNextResources(DiscoverResources.java:153)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.DiscoverResources$1.getNextResource(DiscoverResources.java:129)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.DiscoverResources$1.hasNext(DiscoverResources.java:116)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.DiscoverNamesInFile$1.getNextClassNames(DiscoverNamesInFile.java:186)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.DiscoverNamesInFile$1.getNextClassName(DiscoverNamesInFile.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.DiscoverNamesInFile$1.hasNext(DiscoverNamesInFile.java:157)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.NameDiscoverers$1.getNextIterator(NameDiscoverers.java:143)
```